# Issue with DD4T RestService WebApi with SDL web 8.1.1

Tags: dd4t, web8, api, rest

I am trying to build the DD4T RestService API but getting error have downloaded the code from [Link](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.RestService.WebApi) and followed the instruction as mentioned in the README.md.

```
**Error**    
Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'.]    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +9905641    System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'.]    System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +353    System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +21    System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39 System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42 System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +160    System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
+1068    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82    System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172    System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352    System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule'.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947380  System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
+101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Could not load type error indicates that you are missing Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll file.

Comment: Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll with the version 8.1.0.1239 is already there in the bin folder.

Comment: Also, check for permission as looking through error again, I can see error code: 0x80004005 which indicates permission issue of some sort for accessing Ambient dll.

Answer (score 0):

Is the license file in the right place?

Comment: Hi, I put the cd_licence.xml file in the bin\config folder of my application but i am still getting the same error. is there any other path where i need to keep the licence file.Thanks

Comment: Check the cd*conf.xml files for the location where they expect the license to be in, and modify the location if needed

Comment: The license should recide in web/config directory as bin will have that when you will build the application.

Answer (score -3):

From DD4T team.. "Note that the introduction of the Content Interaction Library makes the DD4T Restservice and Rest provider obsolete. We recommend these features only for SDL Tridion 2013sp1 and older"